# More efficient zsh string parsing / array handling

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, string, array

Is there any more efficient way to do the following in zsh?

I imagine that there might be ways to get rid of the intermediate array parameters `a` and/or `b`.

The script gets some output from a command. If that output is not empty, it skips the first two lines, then it uses as arguments for another command the text before the first space on each of the remaining lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

packages=$(pip3 list -o)
if [[ -n ${packages} ]]; then
    print "${packages}"
    a=("${(f)packages}")
    b=("${a[@]:2}")
    PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore:DEPRECATION pip3 install -U "${b[@]%% *}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

packages=(${${(f)"$(pip3 list -o)"}[3,-1]}) || exit

if (($#packages)); then
    print -rl -- $packages
    PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore:DEPRECATION pip3 install -U ${packages%% *}
fi
```

would be *shorter* and a bit more zsh-like, but I doubt it would be much faster.

You may want to use `pip`'s `--format=freeze` to avoid having to strip the header (gives an output in `package==1.2.3` format for which you'd need to change the `${packages%% *}` to `${packages%==*}`).

Comment: Thanks for the `--format=freeze` suggestion, but I wanted to print the `columns` format so I could see both the new & old versions.  If I weren't printing that, I'd use `freeze`.

Comment: What is the point of `|| exit`?  Under what circumstances does it change the outcome?

Comment: @XDR, it exits the script (with `pip`'s exit status) if `pip` fails.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anything detrimental about using braces around all uses of `packages`?  Or would anything else need to change to take account of that?  I've standardized on using braces for all parameter usages.

Comment: @XDR, no, it's a matter or taste. I don't like them when not needed as I find it makes the code less legible.

Comment: Also, am I supposed to surround uses of `packages` with double quotes to avoid globbing & word splitting? If so, I think that using `packages[@]` instead of `packages` fixes up some problems otherwise caused by double quotes with an array parameter.

Comment: @XDR, in zsh, there's no split+glob upon unquoted parameter expansion, `"$array[@]"` or `"${(@)array}"` would preserve the empty elements in `$array`, but here the array cannot contain empty elements because of the way it's defined (and here you don't want empty elements).

Comment: I now see that shellcheck doesn't support zsh, so some of its warnings are spurious for zsh.